# Android per-app language selection showing all system languages

Tags: android, localization

I've adapted my android app to use the per-app languages and everything seems to work fine. However, when I open the settings to change the language, it doesn't just show my specified languages, but also all the system languages set by the user.

My app supports English (en), German (de) and Russian (ru) but the languages selection screen looks like this:

*Suggested*
System default
Deutsch (Deutschland)
English (Germany)
English (United States)
Español (España)
Русский (Россия)

*All languages*
Deutsch
English
Русский

**Is this intended behavior or can I avoid displaying unnecessary languages (in this case Spanish) in the settings?**

I have the following code for my `locales_config.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<locale-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <locale android:name="en"/>
    <locale android:name="de"/>
    <locale android:name="ru"/>
</locale-config>
```

and in the Manifest.xml file I added the line

```
android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config"
```

as described in [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages).

I expected the resulting settings page to be only the languages I specified, but the result is all the system languages as well, as you can see above.

Again, is this intended and/or how can I limit the settings page to only show the available languages that my app acutally supports?